# Dynamic Tier Price Update Cron

Tags: magento-1.8, cron, tierprice

The store is selling gold products that has dynamic pricing, the pricing will change based on the international gold price.

The base price is dynamic but recently we added tier pricing and how can we make the tier price update using cron? Initially I used this cron to reindex but it has no effect on updating the tier price.

`php -f /var/www/shell/indexer.php reindexall`

The other method is to just saving the products so that the tier price will be updated but the stores has so many products!

I'd like to explore the available options or insights from the board regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your method isn't going to scale well at all.

I don't know much about the gold markets, but what seems like an obvious solution would be to use the currency exchange mechanism built into Magento to achieve a similar thing with your Gold price.

You could define a base/reference price for your products, then apply a multiplier (ie. the market rate) to said price - that is done on the fly using a module based off the currency exchange core module.